# Como saber se o Java está rodando em 32 ou 64 bits?

Tags: java

Existe algum comando para eu usar onde retorne se meu java é 32 ou 64 bits, na linguagem Java?

Algo do tipo `System.getProperty("java.version");`

Algo que seja assim só que me retorne se o Java é 32 ou 64 bits.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 11):

```
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")
```

ou indiretamente

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/WhichPlatform.java).

Comment: Muito obrigado, Perfeito!!